# about ssh2 getHibernateTemplate().get()

Tags: java, ssh

```
public Users findById(String id){
    log.debug("find by id");
    try{
        Users result=(Users)getHibernateTemplate().get(Users.class, id);
        return result;
    }catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("find by example failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

I get a null value. But I don't know why. This function doesn't throw an exception but just returns `null`.
In the meanwhile

```
List result=getHibernateTemplate().find("from Users as model where model.id="+id)
```

i can get data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you post Users.java . (Between I will name it User.java).

What is the type of Id property .Is it long?.
then use  `Users result=(Users)getHibernateTemplate().get(Users.class, Long.parseLong(id));`

Comment: in database the Id column is char.Not long

Comment: then modify the type of id parameter to char and try

Comment: in user.hbm.xml id is that
<id name="id" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ID" length="50" />
            <generator class="sequence" />
</id>
so the type of id is ok.